# MySQL on AWS RDS: Error message 'IP address could not be resolved' when creating entries

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, amazon-rds

I have problems with RDS, I have my App running from digitalocean but using the AWS MySQL database, when creating an entry I get this error in my RDS log:-

> [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address 'X.X.X.X' could not be
> resolved: Name or service not known

Researching on the internet I saw that it is necessary to use `skip_name_resolve` in my `my.conf`

Is it possible to do it in RDS? To resolve DNS issues.

I want to create an entry in my database, I can do it locally but when I do it online it doesn't let me, but the strangest thing is that in the panel it does let me delete entries

Comment: Does the instance publicly accessible? Any inbound rules you specified in the security group attached to the RDS instances?

Comment: yes, I understand that the instance is public access, I think I gave it all the permissions in the group